# Trying to create a net new mdadm raid 5 from old raid drives, and failing

Tags: centos-7, mdadm, raid-5

Long story short, I have rebuilt a new new centos 7 system.  It's a file storage system with 4 identical drives.  They used to be part of a raid 5 system, but now that I've rebuild the system I want to eliminate anything they ever had and start fresh.

My system boots from a thumb drive, so nothing should be using any of the 4 drives I'm attempting to use

I'm getting an error that 2 of them are in use, and running `cat /proc/mdstat` I see the two supposedly in use are showing as inactive.  The other 2 don't show up.

Below is a list of all the commands I know to run, but don't know what to do to clean up this issue to create a proper new volume:

```
df -h
=====
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.6G  8.9M  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root   25G  1.9G   24G   8% /
/dev/sdd1               1014M  157M  858M  16% /boot
tmpfs                    323M     0  323M   0% /run/user/1000


lshw -class disk -short
=======================
H/W path                 Device     Class          Description
==============================================================
/0/100/2.2/0/0           /dev/sdc   disk           3TB WDC WD30EFZX-68A
/0/100/2.2/0/1           /dev/sde   disk           3TB WDC WD30EFRX-68E
/0/100/10/1/1/0.0.0      /dev/sdd   disk           31GB USB 3.1 FD
/0/100/10/1/1/0.0.0/0    /dev/sdd   disk           31GB
/0/100/11/0              /dev/sda   disk           3TB WDC WD30EFRX-68E
/0/100/11/1              /dev/sdb   disk           3TB WDC WD30EFRX-68E

lsblk
======
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0  2.7T  0 disk
sdb               8:16   0  2.7T  0 disk
sdc               8:32   0  2.7T  0 disk
sde               8:64   0  2.7T  0 disk

mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sde
=========================================================================================================
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sda
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sda but will be lost or
       meaningless after creating array
mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/sdb: Device or resource busy
mdadm: /dev/sdb is not suitable for this array.
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdc
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdc but will be lost or
       meaningless after creating array
mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/sde: Device or resource busy
mdadm: /dev/sde is not suitable for this array.
mdadm: create aborted

cat /proc/mdstat
================
Personalities :
md127 : inactive sdb[1](S) sde[4](S)
      5860271024 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

Any guidance to resolve this is greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the result of `pvs`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov whatr is pvs and what command would I run.  I'm not an admin, just a jack of all trades that's a little dangerous

Just running "pvs" shows the boot drive:


 pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdd2  centos lvm2 a--  <27.91g 4.00m

Comment: Just running "pvs" shows the boot drive:<br>
<br>
<br>
 pvs<br>
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree<br>
  /dev/sdd2  centos lvm2 a--  <27.91g 4.00m<br>

Comment: So you can try with `mdadm -f ......` In most of the cases this will do the work

Comment: I used the --force with the same results

Comment: the two drives failing with " Device or resource busy" are also the two that show up when running "cat /proc/mdstat" and show inactive.  There must be a relationship there.  Why do they show in mdstat, what does that mean?

Comment: Try also `mdadm –fail /dev/sdb –remove /dev/sdb`

Comment: It failed with: mdadm --fail /dev/sdb --remove /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sdb does not appear to be an md device

Comment: problem resolved:

I realized the output of "cat /proc/mdstat" showed a device /dev/md127

I assume when I rebuilt the host it somehow created that?  I wasn't something I did, but seemed to have used 2 of the 4 drives.

I stopped and removed md127 and everything cleaned up and started working